# Conserved charges without conserved currents?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, conservation-laws, charge, ads-cft

I recently read (Section 9.3 of [J.Kaplan AdS/CFT notes](https://sites.krieger.jhu.edu/jared-kaplan/files/2016/05/AdSCFTCourseNotesCurrentPublic.pdf)) that we can have QFT's s.t. we have conserved charges but NO associated conserved currents. How is this related to the gauging of global symmetry? How is the charge even defined without the existence of a conserved current?

1. An explicit example is given: If in the bulk of AdS, we look at QFT's on fixed background metric, then we don't have a stress-tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ in the boundary theory, and hence we cannot define currents. However, the boundary theory does have the conformal generators obeying the conformal algebra. Hence, it does have conserved charges, but because of the non-existence of stress-tensor, we don't have currents.
2. One example where this makes sense to me is dynamical gravity since there we define the charges at the boundary, which is invariant under small diffeomorphisms. The charges are associated with Killing vectors, which in turn are associated with isometries of the metric. In the bulk, we cannot define a current since it's a local qty and hence would NOT be diffeomorphism inv. However, can we define a boundary current that is related to the boundary charges?
3. What are the other examples where we have this scenario and what's the fundamental reason for it: Existence of conserved charges without conserved currents?

Comment: Read where? Link? Which page?

Comment: Jared Kaplan's Notes on AdS/CFT from the Bottom up. Section 9.3

Comment: @Qmechanic Should I also add the link?